# Aggregate query with filter in batch

Tags: apex, soql, batch, aggregate

I would like to use aggregate query in batch job but I'm running into an error:

> HAVING expression must be grouped or aggregated

Would also like to understand how can I use count from the query when I'm looping through the record. Here is code for my batch job:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Name) FROM MyCustomObject__c GROUP BY Account__c HAVING COUNT(Name) > 0 AND CustomField__c = 'myValue' ORDER BY Account__c]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> batch) {
    Map<Id, Integer> accCoops = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    for (MyCustomObject__c h : (List<MyCustomObject__c>) batch) {
        accCoops.put(h.Account__c, h.COUNT(Name));
    }
}
```

When I update query locator query to:

```
[SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Name) FROM MyCustomObject__c GROUP BY Account__c HAVING COUNT(Name) > 0 ORDER BY Account__c]
```

I run into following error:

> Argument cannot be an aggregate result inline query

Please advice why I'm not able to use HAVING with AND as shown here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having_considerations.htm

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: This question feels like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: HAVING query provided by @Ayub is correct:
SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Name) FROM MyCustomObject__c where CustomField__c = 'myValue' GROUP BY Account__c HAVING COUNT(Name) > 0 ORDER BY Account__c
however, it is not working with batch apex as it does not allow aggregate queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [doc states(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm?search_text=getquerylocator), the argument to a Database.getQueryLocator can not be an Aggregate query

> You can't use getQueryLocator with any query that contains an aggregate function.

There are two workarounds:

1. If the number of rows coming back from the aggregate query is small, then just do all the work in a schedulable's `execute()` method. Assumes you won't blow up any other limits like CPU time (60 sec) or Heap (12MB)
2. Convert the results of the AggregateQuery into a collection and return an [iterable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm?search_text=iterable) on that collection. The `start()` method can return either a `queryLocator` or an `Iterable` (and in fact, a queryLocator implements Iterable. Assumes that the collection returned from the AggregateQuery doesn't blow up Heap (12 MB)

Answer (score 1):

> HAVING COUNT(Name) > 0 AND CustomField__c = 'myValue'

Only aggregated fields can be added in HAVING filter. CustomField__c is not being aggregated in query. In above given query, you are grouping on Account__c and you can add filter in HAVING clause only on this field.

I don't your problem but a valid query similar to your query would be:

```
SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Name) FROM MyCustomObject__c where CustomField__c = 'myValue' GROUP BY Account__c HAVING COUNT(Name) > 0 ORDER BY Account__c
```

Also, as a separate note,  implement this interface in your batch class: **Database.Batchable**

Comment: thanks for the query but I'm still unable to use the query in a batch class with the following error:
Compile Error: Argument cannot be an aggregate result inline query

Comment: implement this interface in your batch class: Database.Batchable